# Constructing an irreducible representation for a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This is not a homework.

Recently, I have been starting to study the representation and character theory and I am doing some exercises in this field, but I have some problem with some of them, like:

**Let $\chi$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{F}$-character of a finite group $G$ with degree $n$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, show that there is an irreducible $\mathbb{F}$-character with degree at least $\frac{n}{|G:H|}$.**

I think that I should use induced character and Frobenius Reciprocity Theorem to build this character but unfortunately, all my constructed characters didn't satisfy (or I don't no it satisfied or not) the conditions of this statement.

I will be so appreciate for any helpful answer.

Comment: "show that there is an irreducible $\mathbb{F}$-character of $G$ with degree at least $\frac{n}{|G:H|}$" ... I think you mean "irreducible $\mathbb{F}$-character of $H$" .. right?

Comment: No, I mean irreducible $\mathbb{F}$-character of $G$. It is exercise 8.4.6 of Robinson's book.

Comment: Yes, I have the book under my eyes here (first edition) and it says just an "$\mathbb{F}$-irreducible character $\phi$". That must be an irreducible character of $H$. The rest of the exercise also then follows (case $H$ abelian - so $\phi(1)=1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $\chi \in Irr (G)$, and $\phi$ is an irreducible constituent of $\chi_H$ (so $[\chi_H,\phi] \geq 1$), then by Frobenius Reciprocity $\phi^G(1)=\phi(1)[G:H] \geq \cdots + \chi(1) + \cdots \geq n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful hint. I think in summation $...+\chi(1)+...$, you mean that restriction of $\phi^G$ to $H$ has an irreducible summand isomorphic to $\chi$. Am I right? Would you please explain this part a little more?

Comment: The $\phi^G$ is the character $\phi$ of $H$ induced to $G$. Since $\phi$ is an irreducible constituent of $\chi_H$, by reciprocity one must find $\chi$ (with the same multiplicity) in the induction of $\phi$ to $G$. So $\chi$ appears in the decomposition of $\phi^G$ exactly $[\chi_H,\phi]=[\chi,\phi^G]$ times. And this number is at least $1$.